# ASP.NET resources for a C# programmer

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone have any recommendations of resources for learning ASP.NET specifically? I have a good background in web-based programming (PHP/MySQL) and a strong grounding in C# for desktop, winforms and background services, but I have never touched ASP.

I personally prefer online resources, but in lieu of that, books or other resources would be appreciated too (or for other people looking for the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of information, tutorials etc. on official [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) site.

Answer (score 1):

Although they are a bit old, I think [the Fritz Onion books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Fritz+Onion&x=0&y=0) on ASP.NET are still very relevant for any programmer to get up to speed with what's under the hood in ASP.NET.